# A clean non global way to initialize models in Flask

Tags: python, flask, llama

So, I've been trying to create a simple server on my local machine for the LLama models.

So far I've been using a global variable to initialize my model

```
llm_obj = None

def start_models(self):
    global llm_obj
    llm_obj = LLamaModel(q = 4)
    llm_obj.setup_model()
```

But having a global object like this feels incorrect for multiple reasons. Mainly because it's going to create a clutter that should be bundled away into a different logical block somewhere.


Another thing I tried was to extend Flask and put everything inside, but the init gets called twice and I run out of VRAM

```
class ModelRunnerFlask(Flask):
    def init_vars(self):
        # don't want to use constructor. Need to keep track of too many args
        self.chat_model = None
        self.image_model = None

    def run(self, host=None, port=None, debug=None, load_dotenv=True, **options):
        self.init_vars()

        if not (app.debug or os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV") == "development") or os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") == "true":
        # the app could reload, but this won't be executed again
            with self.app_context():
                # TODO: make this multi threaded?
                self.start_models(force = False)

        super(ModelRunnerFlask, self).run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, load_dotenv=load_dotenv, **options)

    def start_models(self, force):
        if self.chat_model:
                self.chat_model.cleanup()

            self.chat_model = LLamaModel(q = 4)
```

I am pretty sure Flask has a way of handling it or other people would have come up with elegant patterns that solve such cases. So I would like to know how other folks solve this problem.


The solution I am looking for should check these boxes

- The model should init only once. (I run out of GPU VRAM otherwise)
- Not need global variables